# CSS layers, Title comes under Image layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I've written html code that includes style sheet. **Image**, **Title** comes under on class and i want to display **Image** on top of the **Title**.. now its comes below the  **Image** layer. and also the **Title** doesn't fit inside data-layer. Help me..
Here is the html code:

```
<div id="layout-panel">
        <div id="tile-container">
            <div id="tiles-panel" data-bind="foreach: data">
                <div class='row-horizontal-tile'>
                    <div class='data-layer'>
                        <div><img data-bind="attr:{src:ImageUrl}" class="stick-image"/></div>                              
                        <div class='text-title' data-bind="text: Title">
                        </div>                 
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css for the above html code is given below:

```
.row-horizontal-tile
{         
    margin:10px 5px 8px 1%; 
    width: 23%;
    height: 90%;
    display: inline-block;   
}
.data-layer
{    
    color:#ffffff;    
    font-family:Calibri;        
    text-align:inherit;     
    color:Black; 
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style:outset;     
} 
.stick-image
{    
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;  
    background-color: white;
}    
.text-title
{   
    font-family: DokChampa;
    font-size: large;
    text-align:center;
}
#layout-panel
{
    background-color: #444444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%; 
}
#tile-container
{
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    position:relative;    
    top: 10%;  
    left: 5%; 
}
#tiles-panel
{   
    height: 100%; 
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
    overflow-y:hidden; 
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you using a javascript library or jquery plugin? `data-bind="foreach: data"` is not standard javascript or jquery.

Comment: I'm using rx,knockout javascript libraries and also a jquery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these property in following class may help you:

```
.data-layer{ position:relative;}

.text-title{ position:absolute; z-index:9; bottom:5px; right:5px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its worked but title doesn't fit inside the datalayer.

Comment: change the values from bottom and right to adjust text if text is so much just fix the width equal to wrapper div and height auto hope it will help tou

Comment: #tiles-panel {
white-space: nowrap;
}

this property creating the problem white-space: nowrap; don't allowed the text to line break after space so complete text is displaying in one single line.so remove it if not neccesry or use overflow: auto;
in .text-title class it will add a scroll bar in text.

hope it will help-full for you

Comment: When I remove  #tiles-panel { white-space: nowrap; } title layer comes below the image layer..

Comment: have you remove this code
.data-layer{ position:relative;}

.text-title{ position:absolute; z-index:9; bottom:5px; right:5px;}

will you please upload a screenshot or fiddle your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so i can help you more

Comment: try this one hope it will solve your problem


.data-table{ width:100%; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}

.text-title { font-family: DokChampa;  font-size: large; text-align:justify;  }

.text-description { font-size: small; font-family: Castellar;  }

.text-type { font-size: x-small; font-family: Castellar; }

Comment: only one tile is displayed and its filling the tile-container

Comment: check your link again
http://jsfiddle.net/gEfy9/2/
i have updated the code hope this is the result you desired.

Comment: I've tried this, but there is a problem remaining layers comes under the existing elements like float:left